# R function to Retention Time for make cumulative by week

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

Can someone help me to calculation retention time based on the weeks and making the result cumulative. The result hoping like this (yellow theme what i want):
[image]

And my code in R like this:
[image]

Hoping the result will publish beside Jumlah_order column

for the data it have:

```
yourdata = data.frame(transaction=rep(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-26', '2020-01-27', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-17'),each=1 ),
                   name=rep(c('yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi'),each=1),
                   product=rep(c("chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha"),each=1),
                   sum.quality.product=rep(c(5,3,1,3,1,1,4,2),each=1))
```

for the code:

```
yourdata  = read.table(file.choose(), sep = ";", header = T)
yourdata 
yourdata$transaction = as.Date(yourdata$transaction,"%d/%m/%y")

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
yourdata %>%
  group_by(Weeks = week(transaction)) %>%
  summarize(Jumlah_Order = sum(sum.quality.product))

yourdata$Weeks <- as.POSIXlt(yourdata$transaction)$yday %/% 7 + 1
newdata <- aggregate(sum.quality.product ~ transaction, yourdata, FUN = sum)
newdata

library(data.table)
setDT(yourdata)
yourdata[, .(Jumlah_Order=sum(sum.quality.product)),
         by = .(Weeks = as.POSIXlt(transaction)$yday %/% 7 + 1)]
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: halo, i already edit my question

Comment: When I requested that you post data (in lieu of our in addition to a picture of data), you reply by adding another image of more data? When we suggest that somebody makes a question reproducible, please realize (1) we don't have your csv, and (2) we are not highly likely to transcribe days you have from a picture into diverting usable. Thanks for adding code, now please add data (not pictures of it) please. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, i've edit my question again and i change my pict into the code

Comment: It isn't cumulative, but I think all you need is to add the following to your `data.table` code: `yourdata[...][, Cumulative := Jumlah_Order / first(Jumlah_Order)]` (where `...` is your previous data.table code).

Comment: thankyou!! yes idk thats cumulative or not. but my senior just saying how to calculation is "the data now/previous". so i just follow her

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give a reproducible example it is hard to give a specific answer. But you can try and use `cumsum()`, which gives you the cumulative sum of a column.

Comment: halo, i already edit my question